# Scan REST controller class using class base configuration

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am transferring my spring mvc application to spring boot application.
I am also transferring my xml base configuration to class based.

I have done most of thing running.
I just dont know that how to scan REST controller package.
Beans are creating, but REST controller beans is not creating.

Which annotation is used ? At where to give configuration to scan for controller.
Still don't know.

In XML I have tag :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ApiServer" />
```

Now how to convert it into simple class configuration i don't know.
Controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = SeriesController.BASE_URL)
public class SeriesController {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "/setup/series";  

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<List<SeriesResponse>> getSeries(){
        List<SeriesResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();       
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responses, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Main Class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println("BEAN :: " + beanName);
        }
    }
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        CORSFilter corsFilter = new CORSFilter();
        registrationBean.setFilter(corsFilter);
        registrationBean.setOrder(1);
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to find out if it helped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use @ComponentScan on your configuration class with base package like the one below to scan your rest controllers.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="ApiServer")
public class Application  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println("BEAN :: " + beanName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@SpringBootApplication is an aggregation of three annotations. @ComponentScan is one of them. So there is no need to declare it twice. This will do the trick:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "apiserver")
public class Application  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println("BEAN :: " + beanName);
        }
    }
}
```